# Android: How to convert drawable to int?

Tags: android, android-drawable

I get the icon of some installed applications using this code:

```
Drawable icon = getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon("com.example.example");
imageView.setImageDrawable(icon);
```

then I would like to add this image to a gridview formed by some image in res. i don't want to change the adapter used with my gridview.I use for each item an icon and image saved in two Arraylist.

```
ArrayList<String> listCountry = new ArrayList<String>();
 ArrayList<Integer> listFlag = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

I add element to my listFlag like that: `listFlag.add(R.drawable.ppt);`

So how can I convert the Drawble to int to add it to `listFlag`? my adapter to view the item of my gridview is given by the code below:

```
public  class GridviewAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private ArrayList<String> listCountry = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<Integer> listFlag = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private Activity activity;
    private Context context;


    public GridviewAdapter( ) {
         super();
              }

    public GridviewAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<String> listC, ArrayList<Integer> listF) {
        super();
        this.listCountry.clear();
        this.listFlag.clear();
        //this.notifyDataSetChanged();
        this.listCountry.addAll(listC);
        this.listFlag.addAll(listF);
        this.activity = activity;
        this.context = activity.getApplicationContext();
      this.notifyDataSetChanged();}

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return listCountry.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return listCountry.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder
    {
        public ImageView imgViewFlag;
        public TextView txtViewTitle;
        public TextView txtViewDescription;
    }

    public void setFile(ArrayList<String> listC, ArrayList<Integer> listF) {
        listFlag.clear();
        listCountry.clear();
         listCountry.addAll(listC);
        listFlag.addAll(listF);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ViewHolder view;
        LayoutInflater inflator = activity.getLayoutInflater();

        if(convertView==null)
        {
            view = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.gridview_row, null);

            view.txtViewTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            view.imgViewFlag = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            view.txtViewDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

            convertView.setTag(view);

            convertView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams((int) context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.r_width), (int) context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.r_height)));
        }
        else
        {
            view = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        view.txtViewTitle.setText(listCountry.get(position));
        view.txtViewTitle.setSelected(true);
        view.txtViewDescription.setText(SessionChoose.DESCRIPTION.get(position));
         view.txtViewDescription.setSelected(true);
        view.imgViewFlag.setImageResource(listFlag.get(position));


        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you going to use `listFlag` items for? As a parameter for `imageView.setImageResource(int resId)`?

Comment: I don't want to print the imageview. it was just to test my icon.

Answer (score 0):

There are no ways to do that... To solve you problem you should use `ArrayList<Drawable> listFlag`

Comment: this must be a comment. please delete the answer

Comment: This is the answer. The question is "How to convert drawable to int?" - the answer is you can't.

Answer (score 0):

Use getId()

```
listFlag.add(imageView.getId());
```

Answer (score 0):

you can first set id by using:

```
imageView.setId(1);
```

then add to listFlag:

```
listFlag.add(imageView.getId());
```

Answer (score 0):

use list of object and then check whether its int or drawable.

```
private ArrayList<Object> listFlag = new ArrayList<Object>();

 Object flagItem = listFlag.get(position);
    if (flagItem instanceof Integer) {
        view.imgViewFlag.setImageResource((Integer) flagItem);
    } else if (flagItem instanceof Drawable) {
        view.imgViewFlag.setImageDrawable((Drawable) flagItem);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `listFlag` list contains resource IDs.
While `getApplicationIcon()` returns a `Drawable`.

Even if you could find out the resource ID of the icon, you won't be able to access it, because the drawable resource belongs to a different package.

Note that the concrete type of the returned icon could be `BitmapDrawable` or `ColorDrawable` for example. And converting them to `Integer` doesn't make much sense.

Instead, consider changing the `Adapter` to work with an interface such as `Drawable`.